# biological sample size when instrument accuracy is weak?

Tags: sample, accuracy

I'm using a porometer to measure the transpiration of grape leaves. Unfortunately, the instrument's accuracy is 10% and it has a relatively slow (60 seconds) round trip time to produce readings when other drivers can change much more quickly (ambient temp and wind speed).

I hope to correlate this data against other parameters that I measure with a much greater degree of accuracy.

When measuring biological data using an instrument of this accuracy, how should I determine sample size?

Comment: What exactly does "10% accuracy" mean? What kind of variable is "transpiration"? Do you have data on the other drivers?

Comment: In the fields of science, engineering and statistics, the accuracy of a measurement system is the degree of closeness of measurements of a quantity to that quantity's true value. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision so, for a measurement of "500", the true value is somewhere between 450 and 550.